# BookingWindowInDays in Exchange 2013 via Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0, exchange-server, office365

I am trying to figure how to change the "BookingWindowInDays" value for a room (resource mailbox) in Exchange 2013 via Powershell.

I do not find the command to achieve this as **Get-MailboxCalendarSettings** seems obsolete (Exchange 2K3/2K7).
The command **Get-MailboxCalendarConfiguration** does not help me either.

Can someone please tell me What powershell command can achieve this on Exchange 2013 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Found it:

```
    Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity *<room id>* -BookingWindowInDays *<n_days>*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity <MailboxIdParameter> -BookingWindowInDays <Int32>
```

Default `BookingWindowInDays` is 180 days and I changed it to 1080 days:

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "Meeting Room Name" -BookingWindowInDays "1080"
```

Comment: The accepted answer to the question details the exact same approach.